# Swift Appending Coordinates into Array and Adding to Map

Tags: arrays, swift, mkmapview, coordinates

My intentions of this app is to allow the user to input the any set of coordinates in one tab of a tab controller, and in another tab, the coordinates will be placed in a pin with an annotation.

The method I have been trying to implement is to use a global array that appends the input coordinates and called in the other class file (with the mapView). I have had a slew of problems in trying to iterate through the array to place the pins, and I am not sure what is wrong.

Input Info class file:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

var locations: [Dictionary<String, Any>] = [] // here I initialize my array

class OtherVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var latitudeField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var longitudeField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var titleTextField: UITextField!
    var coordinates = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }



 // This IBOutlet takes the coordinate input information from the user
 @IBAction func addToMap(_ sender: Any) {
    let lat = latitudeField.text!
    let long = longitudeField.text!
    let title = titleTextField.text!
    var location: [String: Any] = ["title": title, "latitude": lat, "longitude": long]
    locations.append(location) // adding the info to the array
    let mapVC : MapViewController = MapViewController()
    mapVC.iterateLocations()

    }


}
```

MapView class file:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapView.delegate = self
    }

    // this method here iterates through each of the locations in the array
    func iterateLocations() -> Bool {
        for location in locations {

            var momentaryLat = (location["latitude"] as! NSString).doubleValue
            var momentaryLong = (location["longitude"] as! NSString).doubleValue
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.title = location["title"] as? String
            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: momentaryLat as CLLocationDegrees, longitude: momentaryLong as CLLocationDegrees)
            mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }
        return true
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        let identifier = "pinAnnotation"
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? MKPinAnnotationView

        if annotationView == nil {
             annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
             annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
        }

        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
        return annotationView
        }
}
```

The error pops up in the line "mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)" with it saying that a nil was found when trying to unwrap an Optional. So I think the error is that the information is not saving in annotation, but I don't immediately see where this is wrong.

Any alternatives for this method, that may be easier to implement, are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You are actually creating a new `MapViewController`, with local scope inside the `addToMap` method. This new view controller is created programmatically, and has nothing to do with the `MapViewController` instance of the `UITabBarViewController`. Its `mapView` outlet is set to `nil` so when you try to access that property, the implicit unwrapping will find `nil`, causing your app to crash. Also, the view controller local instance will be deallocated at the end of the `addToMap` method.

2) So, what you want to do is obtain access to the already existent `MapViewController`, through the `UITabBarController`. But again, if you try to access the `mapView` outlet before the user has switched to the map view tab at least once, you will see the same crash. This is because the `MapViewController`'s view will not have been loaded (the view is loaded from the nib only when needed, i.e., in this case, when the user taps on the map view tab and that becomes visible). You could force the loading of the view, and setup of the `mapView` outlet by calling `loadViewIfNeeded()`.

3) You are appending the new location to the previous ones, each time `addToMap` is invoked, and then you iterate over all locations to create annotations. This results to the same annotations being added to the map multiple times. You could change the `iterateLocations` method to something like `add(newLocation:[String:Any])` and just pass the last location obtained from the user input.

So one solution would be to replace:

`let mapVC : MapViewController = MapViewController()` inside `addToMap` with:

```
let mapVC : MapViewController = self.tabBarController!.viewControllers![1] as! MapViewController
mapVC.loadViewIfNeeded()
mapVC.add(newLocation:location)
```

assuming that `OtherVC` is at index 0 and `MapViewController` is at index 1 of the tab view controller. Also:

```
func add(newLocation location:[String:Any]) {
        let momentaryLat = (location["latitude"] as! NSString).doubleValue
        let momentaryLong = (location["longitude"] as! NSString).doubleValue
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = location["title"] as? String
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: momentaryLat as CLLocationDegrees, longitude: momentaryLong as CLLocationDegrees)
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

Comment: Ahh I see now that "let mapVC : MapViewController = MapViewController()" does not refer to the actual MapViewController, controlled by the UITabBarViewController. Also, thanks for pointing out that each time the function will iterate, it will repeat the same annotations. However, after using your recommendation, there is no annotation placed on the MapView. (But the app does not crash anymore!) Do you know what could be the issue?

Comment: I suggest trying out the following: 1) center the map to the coordinate of the annotation right after you add it to the map, i.e.```self.mapView.centerCoordinate = annotation.coordinate``` at the end of ```add``` method. 2) Try out an iOS 9 simulator. 3) Try to print the mapView.annotations property in the debugger after you add the annotation. 4) try out the UI debugger to see if the annotation is out of bounds. Let me know if any of the above helped!

Comment: It turns out that West coordinates needed to be inputted as a negative coordinate! The self.mapView.centerCoordinate = annotation.coordinate helped me figure that out!